# Preventing information loss on image subtraction

Tags: opencv

I have two images that I am subtracting from one another quite simply:

```
Mat foo, a, b;
...//imread onto a and b or somesuch
foo = a - b;
```

Now, as I understand it, any pixel value that goes into the negatives (or over 255 for that matter) will be set to zero instead. If that is so, I'd like to know if there is any way to permit it to go under zero so that I may adjust the image later without information loss.

I'm working with greyscale images if that simplifies things.

Comment: you can use the `cv::absDiff` function or you can convert to signed data type (e.g. `CV_16S`) and get negative values, too.

Comment: Sounds good enough. How do I change from 8UC1 to 16SC1(for example) and back again? Or can I use imwrite() without converting the mat back to CV_8UC1? If so, what happens to negative values when I use imwrite? Though I'll probably adjust the image first.

Comment: try `yourMat.convertTo(...)` to convert to the other type. When converting to a more limited type, you can use the alpha and beta parameters to fit the type limites, otherwise the saturation cast will be used. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto You can use `imshow` and afaik 0 value will be displayed gray for signed types. Not sure if you can use `imwrite` directly, documentation says you can only use `8U` and `16U` types and if it works there will probably be some unintuitive conversion/scaling/translation of your colors. I'll write an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how a simple convert => substract => convertAndScaleBack application would look like:

input:

[image]

and

[image]

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat input2 = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna_edges.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::Mat input1_16S;
    cv::Mat input2_16S;

    input.convertTo(input1_16S, CV_16SC1);
    input2.convertTo(input2_16S, CV_16SC1);

    // compute difference of 16 bit signed images
    cv::Mat diffImage = input1_16S-input2_16S;

    // now you have a 16S image that has some negative values

    // find minimum and maximum values:
    double min, max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(diffImage, &min, &max);
    std::cout << "min pixel value: " << min<< std::endl;

    cv::Mat backConverted;

    // scale the pixel values so that the smalles value is 0 and the largest one is 255
    diffImage.convertTo(backConverted,CV_8UC1, 255.0/(max-min), -min);

    cv::imshow("backConverted", backConverted);        
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: For reference, a link to [saturate_cast](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#saturate-cast) that is used by default when casting.